# Is there a limit to Asp.Net 4.0 or IIS7 response redirect calls you can use in a row

Tags: iis-7, asp.net-4.0, response.redirect

In our application we have broken our app into several modules. When the logout.aspx page is called, it builds a stack of logout pages to call, one in each module. Then it redirects to each module's logout page which redirects back to the caller.

This has been working fine but in our new app, which uses APS.Net 4.0 the redirects just seem to stop working. Fiddler shows that the redirect was sent... but the browser doesn't send the next GET.

Strange thing is if I remove and one module then things work. It doesn't matter which I remove, so I know no error is occurring in any of the logout pages.

So, the only difference seems to be less redirects are being used in a row.

Here is the final 302 that the browser receives... it just doesn't do a get to loginredirect.htm:

```
> GET /AmsiWeb/logoutCoordinator.aspx
> HTTP/1.1 Accept:
> application/x-ms-application,
> image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml,
> image/gif, image/pjpeg,
> application/x-ms-xbap,
> application/vnd.ms-excel,
> application/vnd.ms-powerpoint,
> application/msword,
> application/x-shockwave-flash, */*
> Accept-Language: en-US User-Agent:
> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0;
> Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0;
> SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR
> 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; MS-RTC LM
> 8; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
> Connection: Keep-Alive Host: ustawvqa1
> Cookie:
> ASP.NET_SessionId=uf51gkiem0ditfvyi3pvkhoj;
> GeacSessionId=aa6be7f2-9bd5-4700-9a21-e9fa6c0a3b19; PortalPathURL=;
> PortalPath=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AmsiWeb\esiteweb\; ASPSESSIONIDQQRDQTCC=EIMNDBIDIPHCGCMFNHBOHOOK;
> .ASPXAUTH=51C5F3FA040DFEDDFB163D0DF5B5F9D2AAAB91EA76A5388BFE61BC54D83FEF29EB3B0C7886FB473EF9391999D67921B5BE0CEA403F6BA00D5954D8E16BF054212EA4754C40F409473A3990D1A41867D9099ECD45EC229C6205C599727A5BFB19F6DD0CE72B8480CE1C13C10C7A39D50503420A79B70248DF236403C5E632CE8D670DBEF5F0F64F87141A546B8A471EAA163DEA445F76AC6F36D36F7EC3BA805C
> 
> 
> HTTP/1.1 302 Found Cache-Control:
> private Content-Type: text/html;
> charset=utf-8 Location:
> /AmsiWeb/LogOutRedirect.htm Server:
> Microsoft-IIS/7.5 X-AspNet-Version:
> 4.0.30319 Set-Cookie: .ASPXAUTH=; expires=Tue, 12-Oct-1999 04:00:00 GMT;
> path=/; HttpOnly X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
> Date: Tue, 25 Jan 2011 19:20:21 GMT
> Content-Length: 144
> 
> <html><head><title>Object
> moved</title></head><body> <h2>Object
> moved to <a
> href="/AmsiWeb/LogOutRedirect.htm">here</a>.</h2>
> </body></html>
```

My question... is there a limit to response.redirects you can use? If so, how do I change it... if not, does anyone have any other ideas what could be happening here.

(Supposedly there is an answer to this on Experts Exchange)

Comment: Did anything else change? E.g. was there an update to a client-side library in the bump? Browsers should normally honor a 302 -- it is a 302, right? (If there is an "answer" on EE, just open it in FF and scroll down. Way down. Experts ... whatever.)

Comment: Yes, it is a 302... I will add the last get in the change above.

Answer (score 1):

I would go under the assumption it's a browser stop, not the web server. Just like most browsers now ask, after a couple of instances of, if you'd like to show any more `alert()`s, there may be a "Safety" mechanism built-in that it assumes that many redirects is unsafe behavior.

I'm also more inclined to believe this with your mention of visibility of the `Location:` header being sent, but no further `GET` request.

**Follow-Up:**

It appears they do exist in the browsers. Limits [can be changed](http://www.web1marketing.com/blog/index.php/archives/what-is-the-redirection-limit/) with some minor tweaking, however. Also, as I was reading, ensure you're not creating a redirect loop (/PageA.aspx doesn't redirect back to itself, or /PageA.aspx to /PageB.aspx then back to /PageA.aspx)

p.s. Experts exchange, or the [one I was able to locate](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/ASP.NET/Q_22641519.html), has an answer with a link to an [abandoned link](http://www.gadgetophile.com/response-redirect-draws-a-blank/) *(ironic given the text in the link)*

Comment: Hmm... ok, I will check into that. It does seem that in IE6 we don't see the issue but we do in IE8. The ExpExhange link I saw was: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web_Development/Web_Languages-Standards/ASP/Q_25388628.html 

I will see if I can change my IE8 even though I am always redirecting back to the same domain it may still be an issue.

Comment: The accepted answer on there was basically "I don't know of a limit other than memory" (Won't quote it directly as I feel that's a bit harsh to EE). But judging by the other posts I've found, this is false.

Comment: I made the change that link you gave me leads, changing MaxConnectionsPerServer although that doesn't seem to help. Sigh. I guess I'm going to have to change my code to not work this way. Problem is I am co-ordinating with some legacy .asp code.

Comment: You can't bundle the old code in a library and just import it in tot he new code? Or find everything it affects and implement it in the new code? It's probably best you go without the multiple redirects anyways, though sometimes we don't always have the luxury of elevating form over function.

Comment: Yes, given enough time and resources I would just re-write the whole app. We know so much more about asp.Net now then we did back in 1.0 when this project started.